# Regex for stripping specific characters from string

Tags: java, regex, string

Please consider the following examples.

```
The next line is **

_This line surrounded with emphasis mark_

`hey this is crazy`

**bold**
```

Now, I want to figure out a regex that identifies the special characters.
Basically I want to use `string.replaceAll(regex,"")`so that I can replace only these special characters **,_,` from the string. Consider each line to be 1 string.

I can identify that each special character is preceded by either space or a new line, followed by the a string, followed by the special character I am trying to remove.

Also please explain the regex.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Currently, the regex that I thought is like this. `^(\\s|\\n)(\\**|_|`) `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Well, sorry, it is either rather broad or unclear. Removing symbols is as easy as using `.replaceAll("[_*\`]+","")`. BTW, `\s` matches `\n`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to replace only when it is preceded by space/new line. Basically not when it is part of an word. eg. `unicode_snob` Now with the above regex, it will replace the underscore here as well.

Comment: Like `.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)[_*\`]++|[_*\`]++(?!\\S)","")`? See, without exact requirements it is difficult to help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew slightly closer, also the regex has to replace only when there are 2 asterisk and not one. the string might have 1 asterisk which is valid case. also i think this won't remove the trailing special characters. Or maybe need to do another regex pass to remove trailing ones?

Comment: Ok, I can only suggest `"(?<!\\S)(\\*{2}|[_\`])|(\\*{2}|[_\`])(?!\\S)"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Bingo!!! Thanks a lot!! Could you please explain as well how you figured it ? `(?<!\\S)` this looks for space at beginning. `(\\*{2}|[_`])` this is where you say asterisk to be twice and underscore and tilde char. I am unable to understand why this `|(\\*{2}|[_`])` after that? The last `(?!\\S)` is again for space i believe. Could you please explain to me how it works? That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"(?<!\\S)(\\*{2}|[_`])|(\\*{2}|[_`])(?!\\S)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK7fE1/1)

The regex matches any `**`, or `_` or `` ` `` (with `` (\*{2}|[_`]) ``) NOT preceded with a non-whitespace symbol (see `(?<!\\S)`), or any `**`, `_`, or `` ` `` that is not followed by a non-whitespace symbol.